# Vim + Mac: How to use Cmd key?

Tags: vim

I am trying to install the YADR dotfiles here: https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

In the docs, it says `Cmd-Shift-N - NERDTree toggle`, however, when I press command + shift + n it doesn't do anything. I did restart my iTerm but that didn't help.

Am I missing something? The commands with the Ctrl key seem to work, just not the ones with Cmd.

Comment: The command key is totally invisible to Vim when you run it in a terminal emulator therefore mappings using the command key only work in the MacVim GUI. Also, don't use someone else's config.

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the dotfile setup you linked and found his setting to open nerd tree defined in a few places. Depending on your OS it will be different.

[Mac](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/settings/yadr-keymap-mac.vim)

```
" ==== NERD tree
" Cmd-Shift-N for nerd tree
nmap <D-N> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

[Linux](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/settings/yadr-keymap-linux.vim)

```
" ==== NERD tree
" Alt-Shift-N for nerd tree
nmap <A-N> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

[Default](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/settings/yadr-keymap.vim)

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-\> :call OpenNerdTree()<CR>
```

Could be that the documentation is wrong. Does Alt-Shift-N work? You can remap it to whatever you would like the setting is in vim/settings/yadr-keymap-{OS}.vim on your local. Or use a nnoremap in your .vimrc file.

Here is my basic nerd tree config for comparison:

```
toggle NerdTree (ControlK + ControlB)
nnoremap <C-k><C-b> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

let NERDTreeShowHidden=1      " show hidden files
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1    " Hide NERDTree when opening a file
let NERDTreeShowLineNumbers=1 " enable line numbers

" make sure relative line numbers are used
autocmd FileType nerdtree setlocal relativenumber
```